# What is the probability that there will be no matching pairs of shoes in the sample?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A closet contains $n$ different matching pairs of shoes. If $2r$ individual shoes are chosen at random ($2r < n$), what is the probability that there will be no matching pairs of shoes in the sample?

From what I understand the sample space will be, $${2n\choose 2r}$$ but I can't get my head around the number of 'successes'. Please could someone give me a hand with the thought process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to choose the $2r$ shoes from $n$ different pairs. So there are $\binom{n}{2r}$ ways to pick the different pairs, and once that is done, there are $2^{2r}$ ways to pick one shoe from all those pairs.

So the number of "good" cases is $\binom{n}{2r}\cdot 2^{2r}$.

Comment: Okay so I understand the $$\binom{n}{2r}$$, but I don't get why we need to multiply it by $$\cdot 2^{2r}$$

Comment: For all the 2r pairs, you have two choices: left, or right.

Comment: Would you accept my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the $2r$ shoes must come from a different pair. Of the $n$ pairs, count how many ways you can pick $2r$ of them, and then for each pair, count how many ways you can choose a shoe (left or right).